# Does generic NET suite of ICollection/IEnumerable/IList testing unit tests exist?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm looking for a set of generic unit tests that will cover the bases for implementors of one (or more) of the .NET collection interfaces.  I'm sure it's been done many times before, and there's no point in rolling it again, right?  I don't care if it's NUnit, MSTest, C#, VB etc.  I can adapt.

Comment: Have you found something like you seeking for. I have similar task - test my own ICollection implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) has great support for that. It has standard tests for framework built-in interfaces in it which check the semantic contract. This is what you want. If you invest 3h of learning Pex you will not regret it.

This is TDD at its best. Write the test first and Pex will adapt to your implementation until the very last bug has been found. An empty implementation is perfectly testable with pex. It will just find an error very quickly, that is all.

You can factor out all your common testing logic for a particular interface. Pex even supports generic tests which means you can write a test for an arbitrary instance of IComparer and say: run this test with the following types.

Comment: I probably should have specified that I'm looking to do TDD.  As far as I know, Pex only examines the code base and creates tests based on what you've already written.  It might be interesting to point Pex at an implemented collection interface and see if the result can be reused.

Comment: Hmm.  Was hoping for something less involved, but isn't that always the way?  I had a bad experience the last time I tried to use Pex, and ended up just deleting everything it generated and starting over.  Perhaps it is more mature now or I would have been happier using the approach you describe above.  I'll give it another try.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understood everything you said, but you can freely delete everything Pex generates and just regenerate. That is a common practice.